# Image generated using OpenCV for python is larger when run in docker container vs. on local machine

Tags: python, docker, opencv

I am using OpenCV within python 2.7 to stitch 4 images together vertically and then output 1 file. Here is the `cv-merge.py` script:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time
import sys
import os

location = os.path.join(sys.path[0], "n1.png")
img = cv2.imread(location)
img1 = img
img2 = img
img3 = img
img4 = img

start_time = time.time()
new_image = np.concatenate((img1, img2, img3, img4), axis=0)
cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(sys.path[0], 'out.png'), new_image, [int(cv2.IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION), 6])

print("time time: %s" % (time.time() - start_time))

sys.stdout.flush()
```

Running locally on MacOS will generate a file of size ~30MB for a compression level of 6 specified above in around 12 seconds.

However, when I run it inside the Ubuntu 16.04 docker container running a Node.js server. It takes slightly longer (not a problem) but the file size is 130MB every time.

The environment should not matter, since it is the same input image on both my local machine and docker container being used. Why is the generated file size different when I run the script in 2 different environments using the same compression level?

Memory and CPU levels are not being exceeded, and the exported image looks the same.

How I run the script locally as well as inside docker container:

```
python cv-merge.py
```

Comment: they may have different libraries (C/C++) to write image.

Comment: @furas but locally and in the docker container they're using the python cv package

Comment: but python cv uses many C/C++ libraries which can be different in different systems.